# linux awk search and remove on multiple lines

Tags: linux, awk

I have json file with a few cases where a comma appears before a curly bracket

```
 "good": "line,"
 "something": "blah",
}
```

However this isn't always the case,

```
 "also_good": "line",
 "other": "blah2"
}
```

I'm having trouble creating an awk command that only removes the commas when they come before a curly bracket on a new line.

Comment: What about sed or perl?

Comment: Perl wouldn't work but sed would be fine. I'm just as unfamiliar with sed though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `awk` may do:

```
awk '/^[ \t]*}/ {sub(/,$/,"",s)} NR>1 {print s} {s=$0} END {print s}' file
 "good": "line,"
 "something": "blah"
}
```

It will only remove `,` at end of line if next line start with `}`

Comment: almost, if you change /^}/ to /^\t*}/ so that it can accept any amount of tabs I will accept this (my apologize on not specifying that any amount of tabs could be seen before })

Comment: then change the regex to `/^[[:space:]]*}/`

Comment: @DisplayName101 Updated. (added space and tabs)

Comment: @Jotne you have an extra space in [ \t]. it works with [\t] not [ \t]

Comment: could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Explain what? `[ \t]`?

Comment: ^^ Matches a horizontal small space or tab. @Jotne no, i know regeexes well,. I just want to know  how the above command works.

Comment: @Jotne just tried it again and it worked with the space. Not sure what happened before. Thank you

Comment: The above will fail if there's white space after the comma on the same line or a blank line before the `}`. Is that OK? It will also print a blank line when run on an empty file. Is that OK?

Comment: @EdMorton This should do then: `sub(/,[ /t]*$/,"",s)`

Comment: @Jotne that will fix the failure when there's trailing white space on the same line as the comma but it will still fail if there's a blank line between the , and the } and it'll still print a blank line when run against an empty file.

Comment: @EdMorton We can never take into account all without having all real data.

Comment: agreed, just pointing out a couple of the obvious ones and the general rule that we should ALWAYS follow is no input = no output.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and gensub() and abbreviations for character classes (e.g. `\s`):

```
awk -v RS='^$' '{$0=gensub(/,(\s*\n\s*})/,"\\1","g")}1' file
```

e.g. when run on this input file (note the spaces between , and } in the 2nd block are preserved):

```
$ cat file
 "good": "line,"
 "something": "blah",
}

 "even_gooder": "line,"
 "something": "note the spaces",


    }

 "also_good": "line",
 "other": "blah2"
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' '{$0=gensub(/,(\s*\n\s*})/,"\\1","g")}1' file
 "good": "line,"
 "something": "blah"
}

 "even_gooder": "line,"
 "something": "note the spaces"


    }

 "also_good": "line",
 "other": "blah2"
}
```